# Access database from localhost with hostname

Tags: mysql, server

I have a php script running on the server that is connecting to MySQL.
I can connect to MySQL trought 127.0.0.1, but I can't connect with the IPv4 address as hostname.

Is this due to remote connection, firewall,...?

I was able to connect several days ago, but due to shut down of server and restart I can't access it anymore.

I can't find the issue

Answer (score 0):

What dispays your php script ? without logs or error we can't help you.

If your code has not changed and was running before, it can be the network, the database connection (database password changed), IP changed,...

Comment: with 127.0.0.1 as hostname, no errors. With the IP adress: Can't connect to MySQL error 111

Comment: Have you access on the my.cnf file ? If yes, check if you have thoses lines: skip-networking
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Comment: I was looking for it... I'm using Parallels Plesk to access the server. I do not think I have access to this file.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do, try to do a ping to localhost. See what address is showing. If the host cannot be found you put manually in your hosts file.